# TLS/SSL where to install certificates

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I need to provide mutual authentication using TLS protocol in my server-client communication. Now under development, client and server run on the same machine. My colleague created one certificate (.pfx file) for me. As it is a two-way authenticate, server and client have to authenticate each other.

This thread [Mutual authentication in SSL/TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812793/mutual-authentication-in-ssl-tls) discussed in which certificate store a certificate should be located on server side or client side. Now I am confused, as I only have one certificate, I dont know whether it is a client certificate or a server certificate, Can I use one certificate for both, if so where should I locate this certificate for both server and client ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use certificate for both ways, however what's the problem to generate standalone certificate (even self-signed) for client authentication?

Comment: Can you llok at my question related to above question but quite different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738250/mutual-ssl-authentication-with-self-signed-ca-haproxy